# JSF 2.2 - ajax in form with multipart/form-data has some error

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

I try to create upload file form with JSF 2.2.
In this form I have bankCode input box that will ajax to server when loss focus.
And this form also contain input file box with. SO I must put enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to h:form tag for upload file.

Everytime I put enctype to form - the ajax will show error message in Chrome's debuger.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>   jsf.js.htm:359

Example code

```
<h:form id="dialogForm" prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:commandLink action="#{bankController.initCreate()}" class="btn add" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 20px;">
            <f:ajax immediate="true" execute="@this" render=":dialogForm"/>
            <span>Add new bank</span>
        </h:commandLink>
        <table class="dialogTable" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 20px;">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="30%"/>
                <col width="70%"/>
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    <label for="abbreviation">Bank's code<span class="required">*</span></label>
                </td>
                <td>                                           
                    <h:panelGroup id="codeBox" layout="block" class="codeBox">
                        <h:inputText id="code" value="#{bankController.curBank.code}" maxlength="10" class="input code #{bankController.isExistCode?'error':''}"
                                     onblur="return validTextInput('code',2);">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="10"/>
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="blur" listener="#{bankController.existCode()}" onevent="function(e){showValidateIcon(e, 'code');}" render="codeBox"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                        <span class="append2">
                            <img id="codeXLoad" src="#{cdnLocator.officeUrl}/img/load16.gif" title="On process, please wait" width="16" height="16" style="margin-top: 2px; display: none;"/>
                            <img id="codeXWarn" src="#{cdnLocator.officeUrl}/css/images/error_msg_icon.gif" title="Not allowed" width="16" height="16" style="margin-top: 2px; #{bankController.isExistCode?'':'display: none;'}"/>
                            <img id="codeXAvai" src="#{cdnLocator.officeUrl}/css/images/success_msg_icon.gif" title="Allowed" width="16" height="16" style="margin-top: 2px; #{bankController.isExistCode?'display: none;':''}"/>
                        </span>
                    </h:panelGroup>  
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    <label for="icon">Bank icon file*</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:inputFile id="bankIconFile" value="#{bankController.bankIconFile}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
```

How can I fix this error.

Comment: Your problem might be related to a number of potential problems I see. The `onblur` javascript might not be executing before the `blur` ajax event, or there might be a code problem with the `validateTextInput` javascript function.  Seeing the code for the Javascript will tell us more.

Comment: Has JSF 2.2 been officially released? You should expect bugs if it hasn't

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply.
I found that this is bug of JSF 2.2 M10 to M12.
I change to JSF 2.2 M9, it work well.

So I will use M9 untill JSF 2.2 is released.

Comment: Have you reported it? If not, it would not come in final release. If so, please post the report link.

Comment: I still found this error on JSF 2.2 release verion that come with gassfish4. I try to google for couple weeks but didn't found solution yet. Please suggest me the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised a bug with [Mojarra](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2871) which I think relates to your issue as well.

[Stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336795/jsf-2-2-fileupload-does-not-work-with-ajax-form-appears-to-have-incorrect-enc)

PS. Voting for the Jira might speed up resolution as it is dormant since 14th May