# javax.servlet.http.Part not being transfered to Server-side using <h:inputFile>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to use JSF 2.2 new  to let the user upload a photografy to his profile. Anyway I need an Ajax behavior, which I achieved with the following snippet:

```html
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{usuarioController.part}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{usuarioController.uploadImage}"/>
    </h:inputFile>
</h:form>
```

But at the moment my `public void uploadImage()` the `javax.servlet.http.Part` part still null..

This is the controller:

```
@Named(value="usuarioController")
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioController extends GenericPersonificacaoCrudController<Usuario>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3233882970467365819L;
    private Part part;

    public void uploadImage(){
        System.out.println(part);
    }

    public Part getPart() {
        return part;
    }

    public void setPart(Part part) {
        this.part = part;
    }
}
```

I am using Mojarra 2.2.6 implementation of JSF with Tomcat + Weld CDI and Primefaces 5.1 which is unrelated to the question since I am using the native fileUpload component, but I am including just to let you know I also tried using it and it doesnt work with the `mode="advanced"` which use ajax, what make me wonder if it is some kind of incompatibility or conflict of the libraries I am using.

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336795/jsf-2-2-fileupload-does-not-work-with-ajax-form-appears-to-have-incorrect-enc

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the file using the java representation of the `<h:inputFile/>` component; you should not be doing this. As you have it, `file` should be bound to an instance of `javax.servlet.http.Part`, from which you can get an InputStream. The rest is quite straightforward from that point. Your code would look something like this:

```
public Part file;
//getter and setter

public void uploadImagem(){

    long fileSize = file.getSize();
    byte[] fileStorage = new byte[fileSize];
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream);
    bis.read(fileStorage);

    //do whatever you want with the array.

}
```

**Tip:** You should also know that the `Part` also has a convenience method [`write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#write(java.lang.String)) that allows you to write the file to a specified directory, directly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyway my file which is an instance of javax.servlet.http.Part is null at moment my uploadImagem method is triggered.. Any clue? Thanks again @kolossus

Comment: Where is the surrounding `<h:form/>` @MarcosJ.CKichel ? Post it here

Comment: It is at the template, and yes I did put the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute at it, I also overrided all the template to test, and it still dont work.. I am using mojarra 2.2.6 with tomcat 8.. @kolossus

Comment: <ui:define name="conteudoTabCadastro">
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h:inputFile value="#{controller.part}">
           <f:ajax listener="#{controller.uploadImagemNoAjax}"/>
  </h:inputFile>
 </h:form>
</ui:define> @kolossus

Comment: You'll need to update your question with enough sample code to attempt to reproduce the problem @MarcosJ.CKichel . Also look in your javascript console to ensure that the part is being transferred from your browser